# C++ single constructor template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization

Sorry if this is a dupe. There are many similar questions but it seems that none really addresses this problem. They are all a bit different.

So what I want to achieve: Consider a template class `X<T>`. Now, I want that an extra constructor extists for a specific instanciattion of that template, lets say for pointers `X<T*>`. I do not want to create a whole template specification for `X<T*>`, because `X<T*>` should be exactly as the usual template (and that template is gigantic, so copy pasting would be quite a code duplication smell), only that it has an extra constructor. I also do not want to make `X<T*>` inherit from `X<T>` because I do not want to establish a subtype relation between these two. 
Is this possible? I tried it like this:

```
template<T> class X{};

template<T> X<T*>::X(int i){...}
```

but it doesnt compile. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the only two ways I could see it done are the two ways you don't want it done.

Comment: You can always resort to static factory methods or helper classes or, as a last resort, `X<T> instance(*ptr);`

Comment: is there a way I can use static factories as implicit conversions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this, using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> class X{
public:
    X(int i) {
        init();
    }
private:
    template<class U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<U>::value>::type init() {
        std::cout << "It's a pointer!\n";
    }

    template<class U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<U>::value>::type init() {
        std::cout << "It's not a pointer!\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    X<int> a(1);
    X<int*> b(2);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
It's not a pointer!
It's a pointer!
```

You're not overloading the constructor, but you're achieving what you want.

Note that you require C++11 to use this code.

**Edit**: Okay, this code does exactly what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> class X{
public:
    template<class U = T, class enabler = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<U>::value, T>::type>
    X(int i) {
        std::cout << "It's a pointer!\n";
    }

    template<class U = T, class enabler = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<U>::value, T*>::type>
    X() {
        std::cout << "It's not a pointer!\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    X<int> a;
    X<int*> b(2);
}
```

Which still outputs the same as before. Note that this is not quite a good design. Having some constructors depending on your template argument is odd. This code solves your problem though.

Comment: You might need to `#include <type_traits>` for `enable_if` to work

Comment: what is the meanting of `template<class U = T>`? Can I also use other things there like `template<class U = T*>`?

Comment: You should read about SFINAE. You require a template function for the compiler to perform substitution(and skip the function on failure). You can do `<class U = T*>`, but the problem here is that if T is already a pointer, you'd have `U = something**`. I mean, you can do that, but you won't achieve the same as using `enable_if`.

Comment: but in your example, I can now call `X<int>` also with the `(int)`constructor. This is what I want to prohibit at compile time. Only pointers should be able to use that constructor. So dependent of the type, I want to remove a member, not only exclude it from overload resolution.

Comment: Editted my answer. It now does what you want, you've got the constructor **only if** T is a pointer.

Comment: I've done a small edit. Now there are no extra parameters to your constructors. They're all template arguments.

Comment: that is really cool. Can I also add a constructor only if the type is an instanciation of a specific template? I.e., can I also have a constructor `X<T>(U u)` that is only possible when `T` is `A<U>` (where `A` is some other template class like `std::vector` and `U` is an arbitrary instanciation)? I.e. I can call X<A<int>>(5) but not X<int>(5)?

Comment: Both solutions still require C++11.  C++11 introduced default template arguments for function templates.

Comment: Yes, you can use `std::is_same`, which compares 2 classes for equality. @twsansbury iĺl fix that ;)

Comment: can you maybe add that (i.e., another template class `A<U>` and a constructor that only works if `T` is `A<U>` for any `U`) to your example. Right now, I cannot imagine how it would look like. That is some quite difficult stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses boost but does not require C++11.  In either case, `X` has a constructor that takes a single argument.  When `T` is a pointer, the argument it expects is an `int`.  When `T` is not a pointer, the argument is a type that is inaccessible to the caller.

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template < typename T >
class X
{
private:
  // Declare a private type that will be used to prevent a single-argument 
  // constructor from being callable when T is not a pointer.
  struct T_must_be_a_pointer;
public:
  // Branch at compile-time based on T:
  // - If T is a pointer, then declare the X( int ) constructor.
  // - If T is not a pointer, then declare X( T_must_be_a_pointer ) constructor.
  explicit X( typename boost::mpl::if_< boost::is_pointer< T >,
                                        int,
                                        T_must_be_a_pointer >::type i )
  {}
};

int main() {
    X<int> a();
    // Next line will fail to compile:
    // X<int> b(1);
    X<int*> c(2);
    return 0;
}
```